# unable to save Redis ACLs getting permission denied in logs

Tags: redis

I have redis 6.0.9 installed on my server. I am unable to save ACLs and config rewrite. I have included ACL file in my redis.conf to save acl in that file.
My redis.service file

```
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
After=network.target

[Service]
User=redis
Group=redis
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=always
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/redis

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

my redis logs

```
13583:M 07 Dec 2020 08:22:25.026 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
13583:M 07 Dec 2020 08:22:25.026 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
13583:M 07 Dec 2020 08:22:56.275 # Opening temp ACL file for ACL SAVE: Permission denied                                                                          13583:M 07 Dec 2020 08:24:38.908 # Opening temp ACL file for ACL SAVE: Permission denied
13583:M 07 Dec 2020 08:24:44.180 # Could not create tmp config file (Permission denied)
13583:M 07 Dec 2020 08:24:44.180 # CONFIG REWRITE failed: Permission denied
```

Comment: Apparently your ACL file's path isn't writeable by the Redis server (i.e. it ain't in /var/lib/redis)

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue. It seems that `ACL SAVE` creates a temporary file in the same directory as the `aclfile` being overwritten ([source](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/99a425d0f3b7b00896cb855d5de4ae93be1fe3f0/src/acl.c#L2254-L2262)). Therefore, it's not enough for the server to have permission to write to the file, it must also have permission to write to the file's directory.

`CONFIG REWRITE`, on the other hand, creates a temporary file in `/tmp` ([source](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/99a425d0f3b7b00896cb855d5de4ae93be1fe3f0/src/config.c#L1677-L1687)) so it needs write access to this directory as well as the config file's directory in order to move the file. in my experience most systems configure `/tmp` such that any user can access it by default so I'm a little surprised the command is failing at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating redis directory in /var/run and gave ownership of directory to redis. Now it is saving ACL to defined path in redis.conf.